# Why can not remove the decimal point in edit text?

Tags: android

I have this plan in application,when user enter the new number in edit text,the edit text convert that to currency,for example user enter this:

> 123456

and show to user this:

> 123,456

for that purpose write this code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(!charSequence.toString().equals(current)){
                    price.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String cleanString = charSequence.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");
                    Double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat( "#.##" );
                    NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) nf).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
                    decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
                    ((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
                    String res=nf.format((parsed/100)).trim();
                    current = res;
                    price.setText(res);
                    price.setSelection(res.length());
                    price.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
```

but that code first time show `0.00` in edit text and when enter for example `123456` show user this:`1,234.56` how can i solve that problem?thanks

Comment: you can use `replace`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks for answer,which step replace?